# Has anyone got angular 2.0 alpha working with Polymer Elements?

Tags: polymer, web-component, angular

I've been unsuccessfully trying to get the Angular 2.0 + Polymer Component Demo ([youtube-app](http://github.com/rkirov/youtube-app)) from ng-conf working, but it seems to require patches to zoom.js and angular itself, which i'm not able to find.

Need help patching the two for the app to work. OR if anyone can share any other working example of Angular with Polymer Elements, that'll do.

Comment: Currently, this runs up against this bug https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1050

Answer (score 4):

Add [this patch to zone.js](https://github.com/robdodson/zone.js/commit/766e185f4024c4a9ff44243d8be141d31872ff64). It will come in the next version of angular2 allowing you to use the two together.

Source: an example of Polymer & Angular 2 from Angular U using alpha-26: https://angularu.com/VideoSession/2015sf/componentize-your-app-with-polymer-elements/. Starts at 32:20 minutes in.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use at least zone.js v0.5.4 within your angular2 setup. The [patch for polymer from robdodson](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/v0.5.4/lib/patch/register-element.js) got merged since then.